# Deploying Play app on dokku failing, works with heroku

Tags: playframework, dokku

I'm trying to deploy a Play (Java) application using Dokku. I was able to deploy the same application on Heroku properly, but when when I push to Dokku master, the build fails

```
  ! ERROR: You have defined an unsupported sbt.version in project/build.properties
  You must use a release version of sbt, sbt.version=0.11.0 or greater
```

My sbt version is higher than `0.11.0`

in **build.properties** `sbt.version=0.13.11`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default build pack is outdated for play applications, you can specify a new one with

`dokku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala`

See the [dokku documentation](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/buildpacks/#specifying-a-custom-buildpack) for more information about specifying a custom build pack.